# Emgu CV:using HoughCircles detect many nonexistent circles,and waiting for long time

Tags: opencv, emgucv

original picture
[image: original picture]
result picture
[image: result picture]

Here is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFileName = string.Empty;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = img1.ToBitmap();
        Image<Gray, Byte> gray1 = img1.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrUp().PyrDown();

        CircleF[] circles = gray1.HoughCircles(
        new Gray(150),
        new Gray(100),
        2,
        10,
        0,
        0)[0];
        Image<Bgr, byte> imageCircles = img1.CopyBlank();
        foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
        {
            imageCircles.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Yellow), 5);
        }
        pictureBox4.Image = imageCircles.ToBitmap();
    }
}
```

Are my parameters set correctly? Is there something I'm not understanding correctly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EmguCV wraps the OpenCV stuff, so you can get mor information about how to use Emgu methods by looking at the OpenCV Doku. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) is he Hough transformation explained (could be that the parameter count or order varies but in most cases the parameter names match. At the explanation point 4 (*Proceed to apply Hough Circle Transform:*) you get all parameters explained:

```
dp = 1: The inverse ratio of resolution
min_dist = src_gray.rows/8: Minimum distance between detected centers
param_1 = 200: Upper threshold for the internal Canny edge detector
param_2 = 100*: Threshold for center detection.
min_radius = 0: Minimum radio to be detected. If unknown, put zero as default.
max_radius = 0: Maximum radius to be detected. If unknown, put zero as default
```

According to the [Emgu Doku](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/6f78c3d8-fb1a-5983-2862-549c49019d49.htm) these values are used:

```
cannyThreshold
    Type: TColor
    The higher threshold of the two passed to Canny edge detector (the lower one will be twice smaller).
accumulatorThreshold
    Type: TColor
    Accumulator threshold at the center detection stage. The smaller it is, the more false circles may be detected. Circles, corresponding to the larger accumulator values, will be returned first
dp
    Type: SystemDouble
    Resolution of the accumulator used to detect centers of the circles. For example, if it is 1, the accumulator will have the same resolution as the input image, if it is 2 - accumulator will have twice smaller width and height, etc
minDist
    Type: SystemDouble
    Minimum distance between centers of the detected circles. If the parameter is too small, multiple neighbor circles may be falsely detected in addition to a true one. If it is too large, some circles may be missed
minRadius (Optional)
    Type: SystemInt32
    Minimal radius of the circles to search for
maxRadius (Optional)
    Type: SystemInt32
    Maximal radius of the circles to search for
```

So try to use a higher accumulatorThreshold (like 150 or 180) because your circles are pretty obvious. On large images a higher dp could help too, decreasing your waiting time.

Your dp is 10 ( I think it means 10pixils between detected centers) just take a much higher number depending on your image size. the OpenCV example uses an 8th of images height.

A minRadius of 0 should be ok since your image shows only large (yellow) circles.

A max Radios should depend on your image size too - this would remove those really large circles in lower image part.

Just try 5% of your image height as minRadius and ca 90% as maxRadius - or simply use sliders and an apply button to try it yourself